# How to increase/reduce the fontsize of x and y tick labels

Tags: python, text, matplotlib, axis-labels, keyword-argument

I seem to have a problem in figuring out how to increase or decrease the `fontsize` of both the x and y tick labels while using `matplotlib`.

I am aware that there is the `set_xticklabels(labels, fontdict=None, minor=False, **kwargs)` function, but I failed to understand how to control the `fontsize` in it.

I expected something somehow explicit, like

```
title_string=('My Title')
plt.suptitle(title_string, y=1.0, fontsize=17)
```

but I haven't found anything like that so far. What am I missing?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You can set the fontsize directly in the call to [`set_xticklabels`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels) and [`set_yticklabels`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yticklabels.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yticklabels) (as noted in previous answers). This will only affect one `Axes` at a time.

```
ax.set_xticklabels(x_ticks, rotation=0, fontsize=8)
ax.set_yticklabels(y_ticks, rotation=0, fontsize=8)
```

Note this method should only be used if you are fixing the positions of the ticks first (e.g. using `ax.set_xticks`). If you are not changing the tick positions from the default ones, you can just change the font size of the tick labels without changing the text using [`ax.tick_params`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html)

```
ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=8)
ax.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=8)
```

or

```
ax.tick_params(axis='both', labelsize=8)
```

You can also set the `ticklabel` font size globally (i.e. for all figures/subplots in a script) using [`rcParams`](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rc('xtick',labelsize=8)
plt.rc('ytick',labelsize=8)
```

Or, equivalently:

```
plt.rcParams['xtick.labelsize']=8
plt.rcParams['ytick.labelsize']=8
```

Finally, if this is a setting that you would like to be set for all your matplotlib plots, you could also set these two `rcParams` in your `matplotlibrc` file:

```
xtick.labelsize      : 8 # fontsize of the x tick labels
ytick.labelsize      : 8 # fontsize of the y tick labels
```

Comment: Where does `ax` come from?

Comment: `ax` is a matplotlib `Axes` instance, and you will see most examples call it `ax`. Typically it is created using `ax = fig.add_subplot` or `fig, ax = plt.subplots()`

Answer (score 54):

One shouldn't use `set_yticklabels` to change the fontsize, since this will also set the labels (i.e. it will replace any automatic formatter by a `FixedFormatter`), which is usually undesired. The easiest is to set the respective `tick_params`:

```
ax.tick_params(axis="x", labelsize=8)
ax.tick_params(axis="y", labelsize=20)
```

or

```
ax.tick_params(labelsize=8)
```

in case both axes shall have the same size.

Of course using the rcParams as in [@tmdavison's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34004236/4124317) is possible as well.

Comment: this worked great for jupyter/pandas. for example i was looking to change font sizes for code like this: `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8)) df['metric'].plot(kind='bar',ax=ax)`

Comment: I does not work for me. Check out here:

`import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'sales': [3, 2, 3, 9, 10, 6],
    'signups': [5, 5, 6, 12, 14, 13],
    'visits': [20, 42, 28, 62, 81, 50],
}, index=pd.date_range(start='2018/01/01', end='2018/07/01',
                       freq='M'))

ax = df.plot.area()
plt.tick_params(axis="x", labelsize=18)
plt.tick_params(axis="y", labelsize=18)
plt.show()`

Comment: @CarloBianchi It does work. If you want to change the size of the minor ticklabels, add `which="both"`.

Comment: ax2.xaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=7)
ax2.yaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=7)

Answer (score 2):

It is simpler than I thought it would be.

To set the font size of the x-axis ticks:

```
x_ticks=['x tick 1','x tick 2','x tick 3']
ax.set_xticklabels(x_ticks, rotation=0, fontsize=8)
```

To do it for the y-axis ticks:

```
y_ticks=['y tick 1','y tick 2','y tick 3']
ax.set_yticklabels(y_ticks, rotation=0, fontsize=8)
```

The arguments `rotation` and `fontsize` can easily control what I was after.

Reference: http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html

Answer (score 1):

Use the keyword `size` instead of `fontsize`.

Comment: However according to the docs (http://matplotlib.org/users/text_props.html) your code should also work.