# Change fontsize on y axis in barh plot from matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, font-size, axes

I want to change the fontsize of the lable on the y axis of a horizontal barplot (i.e. make the fontsize of "Question 1", "Question 2" bigger). I could not find the solution from the [documentation of barh](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.barh.html#matplotlib.pyplot.barh). Is it possible to do it. And if yes, where can the answer be found?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
 
x = np.array(["Question 1", "Question 2", "Question 3", "Question 4"])
y = np.array([3, 8, 1, 10])
 
plt.barh(x, y)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the font size on a matplotlib plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899980/how-to-change-the-font-size-on-a-matplotlib-plot)

Comment: While this reference is helpful, I wonder if it possible to change the font size for y labels independently from x labels.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: How to increase/reduce the fontsize of x and y tick labels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34001751/python-how-to-increase-reduce-the-fontsize-of-x-and-y-tick-labels)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `plt.yticks`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
 
x = np.array(["Question 1", "Question 2", "Question 3", "Question 4"])
y = np.array([3, 8, 1, 10])
 
plt.barh(x, y)
plt.yticks(fontsize=20)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your answer @Corralien. Could you tell me where I could have found it?

Comment: This is the starting point: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.html. All functions to use with `plt`.

Comment: Many thanks for your comment @Corralien. Now when looking at the information of `yticks()` function there: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.yticks.html, it does not seem to take `fontsize` as argument. How then does it?

Comment: Check `**kwargs` arguments, you have a link to [`Text`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text) :) I know it's a real maze :)